# Invalid request using the Android YouTube API

Tags: android, youtube-api

I'm starting an activity from a broadcastreceiver that turns the screen on and dismisses the lockscreen(by using windowmanager flags). This part is working as planned, the activity starts. In onCreate I initialize a YouTubePlayerView and start playing a certain YouTube video. This works as planned on my Galaxy S2, but on my Nexus 7 and my Galaxy Note 2 the YouTube video doesn't start and gives me a message in the YouTubePlayerView showing "invalid request".

Now, I thought about this and know this API can cause some weird behaviour. I came up with the option that the screen wasn't fully on and this caused the video to not load, I used this to check if the screen was on before calling initialize on the YouTubePlayerView:

```
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    ScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
    if(ScreenOn){
    playerView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "SCREEN ON LATE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                 myHandler.post(updateRunnable);    

            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

So if the screen isn't on, I wait 2 seconds and try again to initialize the YouTubePlayerView. I spare you the code in of the myHandler cause it just works by calling initialize afterwards.

For some reason it still giving me the "invalid request" message. I can see the initialize take place but then everything stops and the same message pops up. LogCat shows nothing,  no errors or weird behavior. I tried this on my S2, it just starts the video without any problems. But on the Note 7 and Note 2 the problem  persist.

I used the YouTube API before, I never had this kind of problem.

edit: onError gives me back nothing more than INTERNAL_ERROR, so that isn't of any help.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. This is really weird, I use the link provided by the Android YouTube app(by using the share button). Then I extract the video ID by using String.substring. What happens, I started building this based on my S2, if I get the YouTube link by getting the extra's in the intent the returned string looks like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=`VIDEOID`&feature=youtube_gdata_player

If I try this on my N7 or Note 2 it returns:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=`VIDEOID`&feature=youtube_gdata_player

So a https link vs a http link. On my S2 I'm running CM, so maybe that's the cause of the player returning me a secure link, but of course there are now 2 scenario's for substring.